# How can I find a tranformation matrix/Mathematical relation between two 5th degree polynomial curves in space?

Tags: analysis, matrices, algebraic-curves, mathematical-modeling

I have the equation of two 5th degree polynomials which they don't intersect with each other. Each curve is made of 100 points and these two curves look similar but there are small differences. I am looking for a transformation matrix/mathematical relation between these two curves to describe the mathematical relation between these two curves.

The equation of each line is defined in the following format and all of the parameters are known.

f(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p30*x^3 + p21*x^2*y 
                + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3 + p40*x^4 + p31*x^3*y + p22*x^2*y^2 
                + p13*x*y^3 + p04*y^4 + p50*x^5 + p41*x^4*y + p32*x^3*y^2 
                + p23*x^2*y^3 + p14*x*y^4 + p05*y^5

I am looking for for a transformation matrix between these two curves to map one curve based on another one. I would appreciate if you could help me with a MATLAB code or any mathematical solution to solve this problem .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it duplicates something posted simultaneously on MSE

Comment: I am voting to migrate it back to mse to close as a duplicate.